# Why I am getting undefined after calling fetchNotes

Tags: javascript, node.js, command

After calling `fetchNotes` from the `addNote` function it shows me `undefined` as `push` method is not defined in the `addNote` function

```
const fs = require('fs');
    const fetchNotes = ()=>{
      fs.readFile('data.json',(err,notes)=>{
        if(err){
         // return empty array if data.json not found
         return []; 
        }else{
         // return Object from data found data.json file
          return JSON.parse(notes)
        }
    });
    }


const saveNotes = (notes) =>{
  fs.writeFile('data.json',JSON.stringify(notes),()=>{
   console.log('Notes is successfully saved'); 
  });
}
const addNote = (title, body)=>{
  const note = {
    title,
    body
  }
  const notes = fetchNotes();
  //Push method not defined 
  notes.push(note);
  saveNotes(notes);
  return note;
}
module.exports.addNote = addNote;
```

Answer (score 0):

`return JSON.parse(notes)` does not store this value inside `fetchNotes` because it is asynchronous, so you get the content of the file later in time.

To do it asynchronously, you can use async/await :

```
const fetchNotes = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('data.json', (err,notes) => resolve(JSON.parse(notes)));
    }) 
}

const addNote = async (title, body) => {
  // ...
  const notes = await fetchNotes();
  notes.push(note);
  saveNotes(notes);
  return note;
}
```

You can also do it synchronously :

```
const fetchNotes = () => JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('data.json') );

const notes = fetchNotes();
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns `undefined` because when you are returning in the callback you are not exactly returning from the `fetchNotes` function itself.

Maybe you can use the `readFileSync` and don't use callback or maybe you can make it a promise and use `async/await`

```
const fetchNotes = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fs.readFile('data.json', (err, notes) => {
            if (err) {
                // return empty array if data.json not found
                res([]);
            } else {
                // return Object from data found data.json file
                res(JSON.parse(notes));
            }
        });
    });
}
const addNote = async (title, body) => {
    const note = {
        title,
        body
    }
    const notes = await fetchNotes();
    //Push method not defined 
    notes.push(note);
    saveNotes(notes);
    return note;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `utils.promisify`